# Multiply char in string by its index number

Tags: python, function, for-loop, indexing

I have to code a function with a non-empty string as input, that must return every other character (`[::2]`), multiplied by its index (`n`) times 2, plus 2 (`2n+2`).
Results should be something like: 
input "red" - result "rrrdddddd"
input "hello" - result "hhllllllooooooooo..."

Given that premise, I tried using range:

```
Input_string = ["c","a","m","i","ó","n"]
print(input_string)

for index in range(len(input_string[::2])):
```

But afterwards, I really don't know how to apply the "2n+2" to each index, and how to apply it to the corresponding letter from the string.

A failed trial looked like this:

```
input_string = "camión"
for index in range(len(input_string[::2])):
    n = index
    m = input_string[::2]
    print(n*m)
```

which returns "cmo cmocmocmo". I expect a result such as "cccmmmmmmmmoooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnn"
It should be noted that in the trial, [::2] results in indexes from 0 to 2 (`0, 1, 2`), instead of the staggered, `0, 2, 4` I would have expected.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide two sample inputs and their respective outputs. I can't seem to make any sense from your equation and the input `red` and output `rrrdddddd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `enumerate`, given a list `l=['red', 'black', 'yellow']` you can you use below function

```
In[27]: def string_multiplier(l):
   ...:     for i in l:
   ...:         res=''
   ...:         for i,v in enumerate(i[::2]):
   ...:             res += v*(2*i+2)
   ...:         print(res)  
   ...:     
In[28]: string_multiplier(l)
rrdddd
bbaaaakkkkkk
yylllloooooo
```

Comment: I'm getting instead the following result:
string_multiplier(l)

`hh
ee
ll
ll
oo`

Comment: @Giparra I replicated by your test string `red` and it worked. Also the function expects a list of strings and not a string, updated my answer for the same.

Comment: You are right, it worked as intended, however the assigment appears to require an index instead.

Comment: @Giparra assignment requires index? I didn't follow this. Also pls consider accepting the answer if it solves ur issue.

Comment: I meant, a range. But your proposal helped me solve the issue, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i cant fully understand your example ,

this code will give you -

aaaacccccccceeeeeeeeeeee

1*2+2 = 4;
3*2 + 2 =8;

considering your string start from 1

this output

```
str1 = str[::2]
i = 1
for item in str1:
    l = item*i*2
    print(l,end="")
    print(item*2,end="")

    i = i+2
```